# How to show popup from library to android application

Tags: android, popup

In Android application, I'm trying to popup window after spending 30min on application (using PopUpWindow for this) this popup calls from library file which is in libs folder in android studio.
But not able to get popup it giving exception as

"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"

Please suggest What to do? Is there an other way to do this?

But need to call popup from library only.

I've used this code for PopUp given below:

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, -1, 200, true);
        Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }});

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this from library, You don't have access to current window. Try showing a Dialog themed activity instead.

Comment: I want to give position to popup like sticky header or sticky footer etc. therefore using popupWindow. Any idea how could That be useful in this?